# Spark HiveContext does not retrieve newly inserted records from Hive Table

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.4. HiveContext is used to connect Hive. I did the following

```
val hx = new HiveContext(sc)
import hx.implicits._
hx.sql("select * from tab").show
```

// it is fine, result was shown as expected

then,  I inserted a few records into tab from **beeline console**

```
hx.refreshTable("tab")
hx.sql("select * from tab").show
```

// still old records, no newly inserted records

My question is:  why the HiveContext didn't retrieve the newly inserted records?

Comment: Have you found a solution, in the end? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

hiveContext.**refreshTable**(tableName: String)  - this **will refresh only metadata** of the table (not the actual data)

Notes from official documentaition : (credits: https://spark.apache.org)

**refreshTable(tableName: String): Unit**

Invalidate and refresh all the cached the metadata of the given table. For performance reasons, Spark SQL or the external data source library it uses might cache certain metadata about a table, such as the location of blocks. When those change outside of Spark SQL, users should call this function to invalidate the cache

**To retrive newly inserted records:**- uncache first and cache again using , **uncacheTable(String tableName)** and **cacheTable(String tableName)**

Comment: the table in the question was not even cached in the first place. Moreover, I tried to cache  -> uncache -> cache , it still didn't retrieve the newly inserted records.  Did your proposed solution work in your installation ?

Answer (score 0):

If the target table is partitioned, You need to insert with 'partition' option. If you miss out the partition, data will not be visible.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename1 PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2...) SELECT col1,col2,.... FROM tablename2
```

Answer (score -1):

On a differently slight case, I have an `RDD` coming from a Spark SQL statement via `HiveContext`. The solution which worked for me after some experiments was to actually regenerate the `RDD` itself.

It does not matter whether you are using the DDL by Spark SQL or sending SQL statements directly via `hiveContext.sql`.

I have seen around people using a "count trick" in order to force the recomputation of a dataset but at least in my attempts I couldn't get to see the new data this way.

Anyway trying caching, refreshing and friends did not work for me, if somebody has some proper pattern here please share.